# Answering gRPC call in server interceptor

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I want to validate call and possibly answer with an error within server interceptor. Is there a way of doing it? If yes how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply respond to the RPC from the interceptor, probably by calling `close()`, and don't call `next`. You will still need to return a listener, but that can simply be `new ServerCall.Listener() {}`.

Comment: Thanks! I see that in gRPC version 0.15.x I can also return `null`. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1665

Comment: If you can return `null`, that is a bug. The issue you linked to didn't imply you could return null. From the code it looks like returning `null` will NPE, although maybe there is a bug where that is not being reported.

Comment: @EricAnderson Can `interceptCall` act asynchronously?

Comment: @anhldbk, yes, interceptCall can act asynchronously, although it is annoying because it likely needs to buffer other method calls until the async operation is complete.